# How to read a specific byte range of an e-mail attachment with PHP and IMAP?

Tags: php, imap

I'm currently using PHP's `imap_fetchbody()` to successfully download an attachment from an e-mail.

What I need, however, is just to transfer a specific byte range of that attachment.  How do I only read a certain amount of bytes of an e-mail attachment in PHP?

Comment: You may be able to use <start.length> syntax in the part specifier.  Like '1.2<0.2048>'.  Be careful, as you may break it any transfer or charset encoding at an awkward position.

Comment: seems like it could work, but I can't get it to work.  is the '1.2' the partnum?

Comment: Yes, so 1<0.2048>, or 1.1, or whatever part you would be fetching.

Comment: ok thanks, yeah doesn't seem to work. but definitely a good idea.. will keep trying